# Stuck with HTML scraping using BeautifulSoup (Python)

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I want to convert activities uploaded to strava to a .gpx file.

To do this I need to scrape strava activity HTML page for the elevation, longitude, latitude, etc... This is stored within the `<div data-react-class=` line. I have included an extract of the website code below. I only care about the information from `{"activity":{"name"` onwards

```
       </li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </nav>
   </header>
   <div data-react-class="ActivityPublic" data-react-props='{
  "activity": {
    "name": "Morning Ride",
    "date": "Today",
    "athlete": {
      "name": "James Whyard",
      "avatarUrl": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GiA8yxgfozOqSJEiwW9srS-VEZU_mV_UM2iHFZxjw=s96-c",
      "location": "",
      "followersCount": 3,
      "followAthleteUrl": "http://www.strava.com/register?activity_action=athlete\u0026activity_id=7487240518\u0026athlete_id=90220142\u0026content=90220142\u0026cta=follow\u0026element=button\u0026follow_athlete_after_login=true\u0026follow_athlete_after_registration=true\u0026follow_athlete_id=90220142\u0026source=activities_show",
      "totalDistance": "452",
      "distanceUnit": "miles",
      "totalActivities": 40
    },
    "type": "Ride",
    "detailedType": "Ride",
    "kudosCount": 0,
    "comments": [],
    "commentCount": 0,
    "achievementsCount": 11,
    "distance": "11.7 mi",
    "time": "49:38",
    "elevation": "246 ft",
    "calories": 526.0,
    "streams": {
      "altitude": [6.6, 6.6, 6.6, 6.7, 6.7, 6.7, 6.7, 6.7, 6.7, 6.9, 6.7, 6.6, 6.5, 6.4, 6.4, 6.4, 6.4, 6.2, 5.9, 6.0, 5.9, 5.8, 5.7, 5.6, 5.6, 5.6, 5.7, 5.9, 6.0, 6.0, 5.9, 5.9, 5.9, 6.0, 6.0, 6.0, 6.0, 6.0, 6.1, 6.2, 6.2, 6.4, 6.5, 6.5, 6.6, 6.9, 7.2, 7.2, 7.4
```

I have attached my code also. My plan was to find the "div" in which the data was stored, then slice the string and zip the data as necessary. However after finding the "div" and converting to a string, `.index('altitude')` returns a `ValueError: substring not found`. I also think it would be more elegant to purely use BeautifulSoup to scoop up the data but I am unsure how to go with this.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

url = 'https://www.strava.com/activities/7487240518'
urlr = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(urlr.content, 'html.parser')

divdata = soup.find('div', {'data-react-class':'ActivityPublic'})
strdata = str(divdata)

print(strdata.index('altitude'))
```

Comment: where in your code is `.index('altitude')` found?

Comment: If it is your Strava data I would use the [Strava API](https://developers.strava.com/docs/reference/). That is what I use.

Comment: @blurfus I have amended my post accordingly - thanks for point that out.

Comment: @It_is_Chris My end goal would be to have a website where people could copy/paste the activity link and the .gpx file would be generated. I think this is outside the scope of Strava API?

Comment: @duncant I have something similar created using the Strava API. It is a simple website using flask but instead of the gpx file it creates a power curve of cycling power based on the activity ID entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your very close with this!

What I would do is grab the div element as your are doing then get the `data-react-props` property that contains all the data your looking for. This is clearly formatted in json so we can interpret as such and get all the information we need from it from there..

```py
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

url = 'https://www.strava.com/activities/7487240518'
urlr = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(urlr.content, 'html.parser')

divdata = soup.find('div', {'data-react-class':'ActivityPublic'})
activity_data = divdata.get("data-react-props")
activity_dict = json.loads(activity_data)

print("My rides elevation was:", activity_dict['activity']['elevation'])
```

**Edit**:
@It_is_Chris suggested using the Strava API instead, https://developers.strava.com/docs/reference/. This seems like a better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You might use `.get` on element to get attribute value, that is

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.strava.com/activities/7487240518'
urlr = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(urlr.content, 'html.parser')

divdata = soup.find('div', {'data-react-class':'ActivityPublic'})
strdata = divdata.get('data-react-props')
print(strdata)
```

then *excerpt* from output is

```
{"activity":{"name":"Morning Ride","date":"Today","athlete":{"name":"James Whyard","avatarUrl":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GiA8yxgfozOqSJEiwW9srS-VEZU_mV_UM2iHFZxjw=s96-c","location":"","followersCount":3,"followAthleteUrl":"http://www.strava.com/register?activity_action=athlete\u0026activity_id=7487240518\u0026athlete_id=90220142\u0026content=90220142\u0026cta=follow\u0026element=button\u0026follow_athlete_after_login=true\u0026follow_athlete_after_registration=true\u0026follow_athlete_id=90220142\u0026source=activities_show","totalDistance":"452","distanceUnit":"miles","totalActivities":40},"type":"Ride","detailedType":"Ride","kudosCount":0,"comments":[],"commentCount":0,"achievementsCount":11,"distance":"11.7 mi","time":"49:38","elevation":"246 ft","calories":526.0,"streams":
```

Comment: Your answer seems to be missing a `(` on the line where `strdata` is set.

Comment: @Scotty3785 repaired